# Get difference in timestamps based on a condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one table.

| user_id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | 2022-05-05 01:01:00 |
| null | null | 2022-05-05 01:02:00 |
| 7461 | null | 2022-05-05 01:03:00 |
| null | open | 2022-05-05 01:04:00 |
| null | null | 2022-05-05 01:05:00 |
| null | on hold | 2022-05-05 01:06:00 |
| 8474 | null | 2022-05-05 01:07:00 |
| null | null | 2022-05-05 01:08:00 |
| null | solved | 2022-05-05 01:09:00 |

I need to find the time difference between from when a user_id is assigned and the first status change. Also, if there is no status change until the next user is assigned, then I need to find the time difference from when the first user_id is assigned to when the next user_id is assigned.

The output I'm looking for is

| user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 7461 | 00:01:00 |
| 8474 | 00:02:00 |

I've been working on this for hours and I can't seem to get the right result. I know that a CTE would work but I don't know how to put in the conditions correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the corresponding output?

Comment: @lemon Hi, I've provided the required output in the question itself.

Comment: tag with database platform

Comment: SQL Server or Snowflake? Those are different products

Comment: @an_analyst no database product is fully compliant with the SQL standard. All databases offer basic compliance but diverge one way or another. Snowflake uses the [DATEDIFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html) function to calculate the difference between dates. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is a synonym for `DATEDIFF`

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with MySQL, you can do it this way:

```
   SELECT t1.user_id,
          MIN(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp))) AS timestamp
   FROM       tab t1
   INNER JOIN tab t2
           ON t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
          AND t1.user_id IS NOT NULL
          AND t2.status IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY t1.user_id
```

What it does is it applies a self join on the two timestamps with user_id and status different from null, then just get the smallest difference in time grouped by user_id.

You'll find a fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Q9zvARR7ya9T55rYhYpLE/0).

Comment: do you happen to know the solution in snowflake?